# Swift Tableview Load Data from Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to display data from my real-time database of Firebase in different tableviews.

In my first tableview I load my first level of my database structure (this already works).

Now I want to see what the user selects in the first tableview, and then display the next level of my database in a new TableView.

I have a function in my second TableViewController.swift file where to save in the selected row from the first TableView.

This way I want to save the next level from my database into an array so that this data will be displayed in my second tableview. When I then debug my new array, I also see the correct data in the new array. However, the data is not displayed in the second TableView.

I guess it's because the data is not 100% ready before the TableView loads.

Do you have a tip?

**Firebase Structure:**

```
-sports
    -Bicycle
        -BMX
            -Bike 1
                -img: „bike1.png“
                -text: „bike 1“
            -Bike 2
                -img: „bike2.png“
                -text: „bike 1“
    -Car
        -Audi
            -Car 1
                -img: „car1.png“
                -text: „car 1“
            -Car 2
                -img: „car2.png“
                -text: „car 2“
```

**FirstTableViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var categorie = [String]()

    func loadData() {
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("sports").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            if let sports = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                for (title, _) in sports {
                    self.categorie.append(title)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        loadData()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categorie.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sportCell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = categorie[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Set the segue's identifier in the Storyboard
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "firstToSecond", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "firstToSecond" {
            guard let destination = segue.destination as? SecondTableViewController,
                let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
            destination.detailedValue = categorie[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondTableViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var detailedValue: String?
    var secondArray = [String]()

    func setIndex(value: String) {
        loadData(index: value)
    }

    func loadData(index: String) {
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        if (index != "") {
            ref.child("sports").child(index).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                if let sports = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                    for (title, _) in sports {
                        self.secondArray.append(title)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let detailedValue = detailedValue {
            loadData(index: detailedValue)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return secondArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sorteCell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = secondArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Thanks to @Jay Lee for the above code.

**UPDATE 2:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not loading the data to the `SecondTableViewController` instance that is presented on your screen, but to a new `SecondTableViewController` instance that you created in the `func tableView(_:=,cellForRowAt:)` method in your `FirstTableViewController`.
The logs are printed from the multiple instances you created from it.

This is not what you want, as you are creating multiple `SecondTableViewController` instances every time a new cell shows in your `FirstTableViewController`.
You should rather get a reference to the actual `SecondTableViewController` that is presented and supply the data it.

If you are using a storyboard, you can use `prepare(for:sender:)` to do that.
We have two choices: provide the entire data from the `FirstTableViewController` to `SecondTableViewController` using a delegate design pattern, or just provide `value` to `SecondTableViewController` and leave the fetching to it.
Based on your code, you can just supply the `SecondTableViewController` with `value` that your `setIndex(value:)` method in the `SecondTableViewController` uses, and get the data after the `SecondTableViewController` loads.

For example, in your `SecondTableViewController`:

```swift
class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {
...
  var detailedValue: String?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let detailedValue = detailedValue {
      setIndex(value: detailedValue)
    }
  }
...
}
```

and in your `FirstTableViewController`:

```swift
class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {
...
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Set the segue's identifier in the Storyboard
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier", sender: self)
  }
...
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" {
      guard let destination = segue.destination as? SecondTableViewController,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
      destination.detailedValue = categories[indexPath.row]
    }
  }
}
```

But note that you already have a data to be shown on `SecondTableViewController` in your `FirstTableViewController`, so you should probably make a `protocol` and set `FirstTableViewController` its delegate.

EDIT:
Your segue should not be connected like this:
[image: wrong segue]
but like this:
[image: correct segue]

Comment: First of all many thanks for your help.

I have now inserted your suggestion in my code (see above)

If I now click on "Bicylce" in the "FirstViewController", I will actually be redirected and see as expected "BMX".

But now I will be forwarded twice (see picture above in Update 2) When I click on "Bicycle" in picture 1 opens (Picture2) and then automatically switched to (Picture3).

Can you please give me a hint here what I am still doing wrong?

Many, many thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that your segue is connected from a table view cell to the `SecondTableViewController`. If it is the case, you should connect the segue from the `FirstTableViewController` itself to the `SecondTableViewController`.

Comment: omg you are my life saver :P it works perfect. Now I can finally go on. maybe I will contact you again :D

Comment: No problem! Glad to hear it helped. :)

Comment: Hello again :P, I am making progress. However, I noticed a mistake now. I'm running through the single children at the top level of my database and add them in a new array. When I then print my array, the order is always different. Sometimes ["Car", "Bicycle"] but also ["Bicycle", "Car"]. How can I specify that the order be adhered to?

Comment: If you don't need a custom ordering, you can just order them in alphabetical order: `categorie.sort()` or something like that. If you need custom ordering, you can use `queryOrderedBy...` methods. Take a look at this [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data). And if you can, use Cloud Firestore; it natively support array types!